# How does Chrome decide how much video to buffer for HTML5 MP4?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, ffmpeg

I have an MP4 video that is variable bitrate, so the average bitrate doesn't necessarily stay consistent throughout the entire file. Because my video is a capture of a computer screen, some parts of the video are very low bitrate because nothing is happening, and other parts are a much higher bitrate because there's a lot of activity on the screen.

How does Chrome decide how much video to buffer for progressive download HTTP(S) videos? I'm running into a problem where Chrome tends to buffer too little, so playback stutters.

If there's no way of convincing Chrome to download a certain *time* of video (and I don't want to just preload the entire thing), can I author the MP4 some special way to solve the problem? I'm using FFmpeg and MP4Box. Maybe it's up to the HTTP server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want more control over the playback of the video, you should definitely check out `MediaSourceExtensions`. They define a whole model for video playback, defining `sourceBuffers` where you can put video data, etc.

Beware it is not a simple to use API still, and the information on how to use it is very fragmented.

In your case, if you go the `MSE` route, you can either keep using `h264` (which is probably the codec your `mp4` is wrapping) or switch to `webm`.

In case of going the `MP4, h264` route, you'll need to generate a fragmented MP4 (`fMP4`) and write some `JavaScript` to control the way you work with the MP4 fragments (`segments` in MSE parlance).

MP4Box has support for the `-dash` protocol, which will segment an MP4 in a way that is suitable for consumption via `MSE`. FFmpeg also has support for generating fragmented MP4.